# Phase Script Execution causing me Archive failed. Btw App is running on test device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to Archive an app from a new mac but it gives a phaseScriptExecution error all the time. Btw it can be built and run on a test device.
Tried many solutions from google for hours and hours before posting this question. none of them were worked. Please help me.

I have 2 run scripts file only

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if any duplicate runscript exist or try clean build.

Comment: also check if path of any script is STATIC related to old machine.

Comment: I have only 2 runsript file. I have edited and uploaded those in the question.